# setting a rule on a location with a combination of text and user_id

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

My database has the structure:

```
users
 User_ddac15a6-1890-43d8-9bfb-a13e9b99499e
 ...
```

That is a user's folder is of the format 'User_'+$user_id

I'm trying to set rules as follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "User_$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when trying to save the rules I get:

```
9:7: Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")
```

How can I set security rules on such a folder names structure ?

Comment: For reference, [$variables in Firebase security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put the $ sign in the middle of a rule name, it must be at the start. But you can get the desired result like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$user_id === ('User_'+auth.uid)",
        ".write": "$user_id === ('User_'+auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx Frank ! it should be  ".read": "$user_id === ('User_'+auth.uid)",
        ".write": "$user_id === ('User_'+auth.uid)" ... if you edit your answer I'll accept it

Comment: Frank - I feel the confusion starts from the firebase docs using $user_id for the location name which made me think it holds the id. I've edited your answer (and my code) replacing it with $location to make that clearer. I hope you can approve my edit. Thx!

Comment: Anything starting with a `$` sign is just a variable. The rules under the $ variable are applied to each child node of the location. The name itself is meaningless, as long as the name in the rule values matches the one in the key. You could call use `$apekool` in all cases and it would still work. Since you have a node called `users` and you seem to store the users based on their ID, I think `$user_id` is a perfectly reasonable variable name.